# Using jarbundler ant task to add dependencies to the app

Tags: macos, ant, jar, jarbundler

I have a Netbeans Java project. When I build my project it create a directory **dist** and **dist/lib**. It stores the Jar of the file in **dist** and other jar files on which the main jar file depends, in the **lib** directory.

Now I want to create a release for OSX. For that I am using the [*jarbundler* ant task](http://informagen.com/JarBundler/) like this

```
<target name="mac">
        <mkdir dir="release"/>
        <taskdef name="jarbundler"
        classname="net.sourceforge.jarbundler.JarBundler" />
        <jarbundler dir="release"
            name="MyApp"
            mainClass="controller.MyApp"
            jar="dist/MyApp.jar" />
</target>
```

This creates the app with the jar, but how do I add the dependent libraries to the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what is needed

The **jar** attribute should be replaced with **jarfileset** like this.

```
<target name="mac">
      <mkdir dir="release"/>
      <taskdef name="jarbundler"
               classname="net.sourceforge.jarbundler.JarBundler" />

               <jarbundler dir="release"
                           name="MyApp"
                           mainClass="controller.MyApp">
                      <jarfileset dir="dist">
                          <include name="**/*.jar" />
                      </jarfileset>
               </jarbundler>
</target>
```

Comment: @oers Why would you delete those 43 characters :D.

Comment: there is no need to apologize :) and it is clear that you solved it, because you wrote an answer. It is superfluous information :)